# Writing json string into file using Windows Script Host

Tags: javascript, windows, json

I am trying to write json string that I stringified using https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js ( JSON.stringify) ,

I am trying to save the string and I am getting an error:

> Microsoft JScript Runtime Error: Invalid procedure call or argument

at

```
var textStream = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateFalse);
```

this is my code :

```
var pref = JSON.parse(textPref);
textPref = JSON.stringify(pref);
WSH.echo(textPref)

// Create the new file.
fso.CreateTextFile("d:\\Preferences_temp", true);
var fileObj = fso.GetFile("d:\\Preferences_temp");
var textStream = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateFalse); <- Microsoft JScript Runtime Error: Invalid procedure call or argument
textStream.Write(textPref);
textStream.Close();
```

Comment: Microsoft JScript Runtime Error: Invalid procedure call or argument

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constants you pass to the FSO methods are not exposed via late binding with `new ActiveXObject` so you need to define them independently;

```
var ForWriting = 2;
var TristateFalse = 0;
```

**Edit**

```
var ForWriting = 2;
var TristateTrue = -1;

var textPref = '{"xxx": "AA \u05D5 BB"}';

var pref = JSON.parse(textPref);
textPref = JSON.stringify(pref)

// Create the new file.
var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");

//create as unicode
fso.CreateTextFile("c:\\null\\Preferences_temp", true, true);
var fileObj = fso.GetFile("c:\\null\\Preferences_temp");

//open for unicode
var textStream = fileObj.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting, TristateTrue);
textStream.Write(textPref);
textStream.Close();
```

Comment: I didn`t post the all code, I am using this constants as well in my code

Comment: The write code works fine for me; does `textStream.Write('blah');` work? if not its probably a file access problem

Comment: In my parsed JSON String I have strings like "\u05D5", maybe this is causing the problem?

Comment: Ah, I've updated my example with what you need to do to write unicode